# Typescript - return specific type in a function that has conditional return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why this code isn't working? Specifically, why union type is not assignable to a conditional type?

Edit: although it is clear why union type is not assignable to conditional type, here there is a type safeguard that in theory should be guaranteeing correct return type.

```
class A { }
class B { }

function f<T extends A | B>(x: T): T extends A ? A : B {
    if (x instanceof A) {
        return x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

[Example 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJa1AZgK4B2wALgJYD2J0BAPACrQCmAHuayQCYzwAfaFgB8ACnYAuaEwCU0lhy69%200APxxo0nAlTR90SgWgTDJCOTBlW1Y7FmI9B5wCdW5Ii7rsA3E-1oru6e3n7IQA)

[Example 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJa1AZgK4B2wALgJYD2J0BAPACrQCmAHuayQCYzwAfaFgB8ACnYAuaEwCU0lhy69%200APxxoCtp259h6g9JKsAbqwBOiVNFvRKBaBPskI5MGVbVHsWdbsB0Bas5EQWdOwA3DZ2aDG2Dk7sLm4ewF6OWH4I8YHBoeHQUblxAflhJNFoQA)

[Example 3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJa1AZgK4B2wALgJYD2J0BAPACrQCmAHuayQCYzwAfaFgB8ACnYAuaEwCU0lhy69%200APxxoCtp259h6g9JKsAbqwBOiVNFvRKBaBPskI5MGVbVHsWdbsB0Bas5EQWdOzQkHAA3DZ2aPG2Dk6RlK7unt7CfghJgcGh4dCR0VhxAYkBhWEkcchAA)

This can be solved using function overloads but in my case that is not convenient: signature of `f` is big and complex and I don't want to repeat it in every overload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A { t: "A" }
class EA extends A { et: "EA" }
class B { t: "B" }
class C { t: "C" }

function f<T extends A | B>(x: T extends A ? A : B): T extends A ? A : B {
    if (x instanceof A) {
        return x;
    }
    return x;
    
}
f<A>(new A())//return A
f<EA>(new EA())//return A
f<B>(new B())//return B
f<C>(new C())//TYPE ERROR
```

Generic type T extends interface not class.